# Can Castle Validators work with DataAnnotations attributes?

Tags: data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation, castle-validators

Is there a way of making DataAnnotations attributes such as [Required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) to work with Castle [Validators](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/manual/validators.html)?

I know Castle has its own attributes - but I am wanting to use the same attribute for the view and business logic. So I want the attributes to be used for the view validation and any business logic validation. I am aware this approach is not ideal.